# Mouse USB not working, dmesg show errors

Tags: debian, usb-drive

My mouse is not working ok, randomly reacts. The USB keyboard works 100% ok.

This is the output (last part, not all) for: `dmesg`

```
 2092.345809] usb 1-3: USB disconnect, device number 87
[ 2100.936787] usb 1-3: new low-speed USB device number 88 using xhci_hcd
[ 2101.088200] usb 1-3: New USB device found, idVendor=0000, idProduct=0538, bcdDevice= 1.00
[ 2101.088207] usb 1-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
[ 2101.088212] usb 1-3: Product:  USB OPTICAL MOUSE
[ 2101.091881] input:  USB OPTICAL MOUSE as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.0/0003:0000:0538.0037/input/input75
[ 2101.092496] hid-generic 0003:0000:0538.0037: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [ USB OPTICAL MOUSE] on usb-0000:00:14.0-3/input0
[ 2102.921981] usb 1-3: USB disconnect, device number 88
[ 2108.957420] pcieport 0000:00:1d.0: AER: Multiple Corrected error received: 0000:00:1d.0
[ 2108.957437] pcieport 0000:00:1d.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, (Transmitter ID)
[ 2108.957445] pcieport 0000:00:1d.0:   device [8086:9db0] error status/mask=00001000/00002000
[ 2108.957451] pcieport 0000:00:1d.0:    [12] Timeout               
[ 2118.700577] usb 1-4: new low-speed USB device number 89 using xhci_hcd
[ 2118.851854] usb 1-4: New USB device found, idVendor=0000, idProduct=0538, bcdDevice= 1.00
[ 2118.851859] usb 1-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
[ 2118.851862] usb 1-4: Product:  USB OPTICAL MOUSE
[ 2118.855588] input:  USB OPTICAL MOUSE as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.0/0003:0000:0538.0038/input/input76
[ 2118.855911] hid-generic 0003:0000:0538.0038: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [ USB OPTICAL MOUSE] on usb-0000:00:14.0-4/input0
[ 2130.139350] pcieport 0000:00:1d.0: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1d.0
[ 2130.139358] pcieport 0000:00:1d.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, (Transmitter ID)
[ 2130.139360] pcieport 0000:00:1d.0:   device [8086:9db0] error status/mask=00001000/00002000
[ 2130.139362] pcieport 0000:00:1d.0:    [12] Timeout               
[ 2134.896771] usb 1-4: USB disconnect, device number 89
[ 2136.216604] usb 1-4: new low-speed USB device number 90 using xhci_hcd
[ 2136.368546] usb 1-4: New USB device found, idVendor=0000, idProduct=0538, bcdDevice= 1.00
[ 2136.368555] usb 1-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
[ 2136.368560] usb 1-4: Product:  USB OPTICAL MOUSE
[ 2136.372986] input:  USB OPTICAL MOUSE as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.0/0003:0000:0538.0039/input/input77
[ 2136.373393] hid-generic 0003:0000:0538.0039: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [ USB OPTICAL MOUSE] on usb-0000:00:14.0-4/input0
[ 2210.137354] pcieport 0000:00:1d.0: AER: Multiple Corrected error received: 0000:00:1d.0
[ 2210.137426] pcieport 0000:00:1d.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, (Transmitter ID)
[ 2210.137434] pcieport 0000:00:1d.0:   device [8086:9db0] error status/mask=00001000/00002000
[ 2210.137440] pcieport 0000:00:1d.0:    [12] Timeout               
[ 2260.011761] [drm:intel_pipe_update_end [i915]] *ERROR* Atomic update failure on pipe A (start=136004 end=136005) time 230 us, min 763, max 767, scanline start 761, end 770
[ 2260.137119] pcieport 0000:00:1d.0: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1d.0
[ 2260.137132] pcieport 0000:00:1d.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, (Transmitter ID)
[ 2260.137140] pcieport 0000:00:1d.0:   device [8086:9db0] error status/mask=00001000/00002000
[ 2260.137145] pcieport 0000:00:1d.0:    [12] Timeout               
[ 2346.478904] pcieport 0000:00:1d.1: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1d.1
[ 2346.478911] pcieport 0000:00:1d.1: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, (Transmitter ID)
[ 2346.478916] pcieport 0000:00:1d.1:   device [8086:9db1] error status/mask=00001000/00002000
[ 2346.478918] pcieport 0000:00:1d.1:    [12] Timeout               
[ 2378.262836] pcieport 0000:00:1d.1: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1d.1
[ 2378.262856] pcieport 0000:00:1d.1: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, (Transmitter ID)
[ 2378.262865] pcieport 0000:00:1d.1:   device [8086:9db1] error status/mask=00001000/00002000
[ 2378.262871] pcieport 0000:00:1d.1:    [12] Timeout               
[ 2378.395942] pcieport 0000:00:1d.1: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1d.1
[ 2378.395954] pcieport 0000:00:1d.1: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, (Transmitter ID)
[ 2378.395962] pcieport 0000:00:1d.1:   device [8086:9db1] error status/mask=00001000/00002000
[ 2378.395968] pcieport 0000:00:1d.1:    [12] Timeout               
[ 2389.538783] usb 1-4: USB disconnect, device number 90
[ 2420.135693] pcieport 0000:00:1d.0: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1d.0
[ 2420.135698] pcieport 0000:00:1d.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, (Transmitter ID)
[ 2420.135702] pcieport 0000:00:1d.0:   device [8086:9db0] error status/mask=00001000/00002000
[ 2420.135703] pcieport 0000:00:1d.0:    [12] Timeout               
[ 2461.019286] [drm:intel_pipe_update_end [i915]] *ERROR* Atomic update failure on pipe A (start=148065 end=148066) time 164 us, min 763, max 767, scanline start 762, end 768
[ 2478.590533] usb 1-4: new low-speed USB device number 92 using xhci_hcd
[ 2478.741853] usb 1-4: New USB device found, idVendor=0000, idProduct=0538, bcdDevice= 1.00
[ 2478.741859] usb 1-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
[ 2478.741862] usb 1-4: Product:  USB OPTICAL MOUSE
[ 2478.745569] input:  USB OPTICAL MOUSE as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.0/0003:0000:0538.003A/input/input78
[ 2478.745844] hid-generic 0003:0000:0538.003A: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [ USB OPTICAL MOUSE] on usb-0000:00:14.0-4/input0
[ 2484.022559] pcieport 0000:00:1d.1: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1d.1
[ 2484.022573] pcieport 0000:00:1d.1: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, (Transmitter ID)
[ 2484.022582] pcieport 0000:00:1d.1:   device [8086:9db1] error status/mask=00001000/00002000
[ 2484.022587] pcieport 0000:00:1d.1:    [12] Timeout               
[ 2513.610294] pcieport 0000:00:1d.1: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1d.1
[ 2513.610316] pcieport 0000:00:1d.1: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, (Transmitter ID)
[ 2513.610332] pcieport 0000:00:1d.1:   device [8086:9db1] error status/mask=00001000/00002000
[ 2513.610342] pcieport 0000:00:1d.1:    [12] Timeout               
[ 2563.002716] usb 1-4: USB disconnect, device number 92
[ 2563.910439] usb 1-4: new low-speed USB device number 93 using xhci_hcd
[ 2564.065855] usb 1-4: New USB device found, idVendor=0000, idProduct=0538, bcdDevice= 1.00
[ 2564.065861] usb 1-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
[ 2564.065864] usb 1-4: Product:  USB OPTICAL MOUSE
[ 2564.069585] input:  USB OPTICAL MOUSE as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.0/0003:0000:0538.003B/input/input79
[ 2564.069861] hid-generic 0003:0000:0538.003B: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [ USB OPTICAL MOUSE] on usb-0000:00:14.0-4/input0
[ 2565.706521] pcieport 0000:00:1d.1: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1d.1
[ 2565.706532] pcieport 0000:00:1d.1: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, (Transmitter ID)
[ 2565.706541] pcieport 0000:00:1d.1:   device [8086:9db1] error status/mask=00001000/00002000
[ 2565.706547] pcieport 0000:00:1d.1:    [12] Timeout
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This usually happens because the mouse cable is broken or the plug is defective. The mouse disconnects and reconnects again. It is not available between those two events, so it might look jumpy or unreliable.

You can check if that is the case by doing:

```
$ sudo tail -f /var/log/kern.log
```

and moving the cable, or the mouse. If that triggers the reconnection then that's the problem (a hardware one).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I see error while moving my mouse and it stops function. But it's weird because this start after a reboot, I don't get it.

Comment: Well, yes. I move the cable near to the mouse and I get those errors in CLI